# ASP.NET RadioButtonList | Setting ListItem Value in For Loop

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist, code-behind

Is it possible to add the `ListItem` values in the code-behind within a `for` loop?

If so, what is it?

Here is my current code:

```
rblContentTypesGetAll.Items.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  rblContentTypesGetAll.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["contentType"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rblContentTypesGetAll.Items.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  rblContentTypesGetAll.Items.Add(new ListItem(dt.Rows[i]["contentType"].ToString(),dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString());
}
```

Needed to add `new ListItem` and then comma-separate them.